# How do I share variables between C and C++ code?

Tags: c++, c, segmentation-fault

I'm working on a C++ project that implements C code and I'm stuck on a segmentation fault. The segfault occures when I try to access a global C variable in my C++ code.

Overview of the code:
I have a single c file called video_stage.c with the following code snippet:

```c
#include "video_stage.h"

uint8_t*  pixbuf_data = NULL;    //pointer to video buffer
vp_os_mutex_t  video_update_lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;  

C_RESULT output_gtk_stage_transform( void *cfg, vp_api_io_data_t *in, vp_api_io_data_t *out)
{
   vp_os_mutex_lock(&video_update_lock);

   /* Get a reference to the last decoded picture */
   pixbuf_data      = (uint8_t*)in->buffers[0];

   vp_os_mutex_unlock(&video_update_lock);
   return (SUCCESS);
}
```

This function is periodically called by other C code and updates the pixbuf_data pointer witch points to an RGB videoframe.

It's header file video_stage.h:

```c
#ifndef _IHM_STAGES_O_GTK_H
#define _IHM_STAGES_O_GTK_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#include <config.h>
#include <VP_Api/vp_api_thread_helper.h>
#include <VP_Api/vp_api.h>                  //hier zit vp_os_mutex in geinclude

PROTO_THREAD_ROUTINE(video_stage, data);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

extern uint8_t*  pixbuf_data;
extern vp_os_mutex_t  video_update_lock;

#endif // _IHM_STAGES_O_GTK_H
```

The header file contains the extern declaration of the pixbuf_data pointer.

And here the cpp file: device.cc:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "video_stage.h"

int ardrone_update(ardrone_t *d)
{
    uint8_t x;

    x = pixbuf_data[0];            //no problem here, this is executed
    std::cout << 5 << std::endl;   //this is executed too
    std::cout << x << std::endl;   //segfault occures here

}
```

When the function in the cpp file is called (by other cpp code), a segfault occures at the cout instruction that prints x.

When I do a printf of the first element of the buffer in the c file, I get what I expect.

I'm sure it has something to do with the mixing of c and c++ code, but according to my research I've done the stuff to make both c and c++ code compatible here.

Comment: Asking "how do I do XYZ without getting a segfault" is pointless. If you get a segfault, you wrote a wrong program, so it's like asking "how do I do XYZ without doing it wrong?"  And that's just the same as "how do I do XYZ?".

Comment: Do you actually get '5' printed when segfault occurs? Have you tried to check assembly code generated for ardrone_update function (try gcc/g++ with -S option for that)?

Answer (score 3):

In C++ code `pixbuf_data` defined in a C source must be declared with C linkage:

```
extern "C" uint8_t*  pixbuf_data;
```

Without `extern "C"` the C++ code must not link, unless there is another (duplicate) definition of `pixbuf_data` with C++ linkage.

Comment: I thought that `extern "C"` would only make a difference for functions. C++ would mangle names of variables?

Comment: C++ mangles variable names as well because it needs to mix in variable namespace name or class name for a static variable.

Comment: Hm, my compiler (gcc) doesn't for names in global scope I checked. And as far as I understand, OP has a completely linked program, so this can't be an issue and doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @JensGustedt: I checked and you're right, `gcc` doesn't mangle a global variable defined in a C++ translation unit. That explains why it links. Pedantically, it's still undefined behaviour according to C++ standard. Anyway, it must be another issue that causes the segfault here.

Comment: Indeed weird that someone is coming back to that very old question and has nothing better to do than downvoting it. Perhaps the question title attracts people that expect more to find here. If he'd were a regular, the OP would probably have accepted my answer, at least he said that it solved his problem. But this doesn't make your answer less worthy.

Answer (score 1):

get yourself a debugger and run your program under that. The tracing code does not tell you at all where the segfault appears, IO is slow.

In the code that you show us, you don't seem to allocate memory for `pixbuf_data`. Anything can happen when you access that without assigning a valid pointer to it.

Comment: Wel I gues you gave me the solution. Pixbuf had a valid location to point to, but that location was only valid after a while: the function ardrone_update was called before output_gtk_stage_transform at the start of the program (multi threaded program). Problem is solved now :)

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to share variable between C project and c++ project. but when i build my solution i got "error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "struct configuration g_conf ". This what i did:

==== In C project ==

I create a header file and on it i create my struct

```
typedef struct{ int maxUser; }Configuration;
extern Configuration conf;
```

==== In C++ project =======

In the main file :

```
#include "../ProjectC/header.h"

int main(){ conf.maxUser = 10; }
```